# Anyone run into this: "DeleteRestrictedByFkException not found in section Exception"

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, exception

I came across this earlier today while working on a custom VF page and I was trying to delete a record from an object.

Seems its stemming from the delete trigger or delete action but the exception shown is bizarre and doesn't make any sense.

Has anyone come across this? Is this a bug on SFDC side?

Any suggestions on resolving or going about debugging this?

I came across just one link while researching this: 
http://blog.crmscience.com/2013/09/deleterestrictedbyfkexception-not-found.html

Comment: The article you [link](http://blog.crmscience.com/2013/09/deleterestrictedbyfkexception-not-found.html) to does a really good job of summarising the issue. This appears to be a known issue in Salesforce related to how the DELETE_FAILED DmlException is displayed in the Apex pageMessages.